# How is clock bus different than peripheral clock in STM32?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, c, i2c

Been looking to clarify this confusion: how is the clock that a specific peripheral is on (APB1, APB2 etc) different than the peripheral clock itself?

Say, `I2C1` peripheral hangs on `APB1` bus which has a frequency of 42MHz, whereas there's a `CCR` register for I2C peripheral that needs to be programmed to specify `SCLK`.

Is it that the clock bus frequency defines the maximum frequency the peripheral can use up to (which I think kind of makes sense)?

Comment: Yes, if I2C1 is connected to APB1, then that’s what the peripheral operates at, isn’t it? How’s that different than SCL that you set?

Comment: stm32's have different cores and designs, and there is a detailed clock tree diagram and description of each clock.  Which chip and what part of that diagram or description do you not understand?

Comment: once you get down to a clock that feeds a peripheral that is the clock that drives that logic, which doesnt necessarily mean that is how fast the i2c bus clock can go you have to look at the i2c peripheral for that specific device and see what the documentation says about what clock is available to drive the i2c bus clock and what the options are for divisors.

Comment: @old_timer - in the datasheet, we can see `I2C1` is connected to `APB1` bus which runs at 42MHz. So that's the bus acting as a source for different peripherals, but what does that mean to `I2C1` peripheral in specific? i2c clock is limited to 42MHz?

Comment: @xyf I2C cant reach 42Mbps to begin with, not to mention the peripheral has to actualy take multiple actions for each bit received or sent so the transmission clock cannot be as fast as the clock running its internal logic

Comment: @DKNguyen - yes, but what i'm trying to get at is i2c1 is fed by a source of 42MHz clock and the i2c1 peripheral uses the clock according to its needs (which has to be lesser than the peripheral clock as you mentioned i.e 42MHz), right? Same goes for other peripherals

Comment: Yes. correct...

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/pttgKCK
`fclk` is the peripheral clock, which refers to APB1 in case of usart hooked to APB1 clock bus, or is it the system core clock (16MHz)?

Comment: search fclk in the manual until you find its definition. names like that are scattered and i never remember. i might have been mistaken in my post about the bus clock feeding the peripheral. fclk might be the PLL output

Comment: I checked. You can select the clock source for some peripherals. Like the bus clock, PLL output, etc. Others are fixed to bus clock. Check Reset and Clock Control section.

Comment: you mean the prescalers? to me it makes more sense to interpret `fpclk` as peripheral clock which for `USART2` is `APB1` which runs at 42MHz.

Comment: @xyf My point is that the I2C probably has multiple clock sources to choose from, and whatever you pick is probably whatever fclk will be. With USART, for example, fck is used with prescalers to determine the baud rate, but fck can be selected to be the bus clock, system clock, oscillator, or PLL.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean when you say "peripheral clock"?

A peripheral is fed the clock of whatever bus it is connected to, the PLL, oscillator, or system clock (selectable for some peripherals and fixed for others). It may or may not use this clock as to run a portion of, or the entire peripheral.

This clock may subdivided to run slower circuitry inside of the peripheral which may or may not manifest externally to the peripheral. This may happen multiple times and at multiple levels in the same peripheral.

For example, a UART might run off a 48MHz bus clock. But the UART might transmit and receive at 1Mbps. But a UART 8x oversamples received signals so some part of it must run at 8MHz. All these are subdivisons of the bus clock.

A sigma delta ADC might step the bus clock down to run the decimation digital filter which uses multiple samples to construct a single output reading, step clock down yet again for the actual sampling (oversampling), and step that down yet again for the actual output (though this would be tightly linked with the decimation filter clock if it is even separate at all).

Similarly, a SARs ADC has a sampling clock, and a faster clock that does the actual cap charge redistribution on each sample to figure out the bits before the next sample comes in, and ultimately the even faster bus clock from which the first two originate.

Hopefully you can understand now why it is vague when you ask "what frequency the peripheral operates at?" without getting specific about what exactly you are referring to.

Personally, when I say "peripheral clock" (the STM manual does this too I believe), I am referring to the clock feeding the entire peripheral from the bus, PLL, whatever. Everything past that is something like "the sampling clock" (for an ADC) or the "serial clock" for the communication bus itself. There is only one clock for the peripheral so I call it *the* peripheral clock, but there can be multiple clocks inside the peripheral. These are not usually referred to as clocks though.

Answer (score 0):

No, not in general (and probably not here).

The actual architecture in such a microcontroller depends on the individual model, but in general, modern rich microcontrollers have both a clock tree that distributes rationally related clocks throughout the microcontroller for things like bus clocks, memory clocks and CPU clocking and independent clocks for things like the RTC and serial peripherals.